# error in move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying upload an image using:

```
$sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = "upload/".$_FILES['file']['name'];

move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath) ;
```

but there is always an error like this:

> Warning:move_uploaded_file(upload/13709_965665460118582_8676485775333023105_n.jpg):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\AjaX\ajax_php_file.php on line 23
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
>   'C:\xampp\tmp\php3C97.tmp' to
>   'upload/13709_965665460118582_8676485775333023105_n.jpg' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\AjaX\ajax_php_file.php on line 23

What am I gonna do with this thing?

Comment: Does the directory `upload/` exist?

Comment: The directory `upload` is set to be a subdirectory of whatever location the PHP script is running from.

Comment: Either print or log the $sourcePath in error log.

Comment: Change the chmod of the `upload` directory to `777` and try it again.

Comment: @Tom He is using windows.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that

- the file was uploaded without an error ([php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php))
- the destination directory exists and is writable

Answer (score 0):

The anwser is right in front of you:

> Warning:move_uploaded_file(upload/13709_965665460118582_8676485775333023105_n.jpg):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\AjaX\ajax_php_file.php on line

The warning clearly states "No such file or directory", this is your issue,

the directory `<script location>/upload` does not exist, what you may want to do is use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to get an absolute file path for your destination location.

Typically the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` value is the root of your domain as a filepath string, such that `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is the same location in the file structure as `http://www.yourwebdomain.com/<here>`.

Comment: Also, and I'm not so sure about this, try to substitute the `upload/` with `upload\ ` to fit with the rest of the file tree structure. Your path you are teling the PHP to use is `C:\xampp\htdocs\AjaX\upload\ ` if that path doesn't exist, then create it.